# angular 7.0.5 ng new doesn't ask Would you like to add Angular routing?.... etc

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular7

Someone could guide me to know why I can not generate a new project with the new version of angular 7

Desired result:

[image]

ng new firebase-auth
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS

obtained result:

```
 $ ng new appAtlas
    CREATE appAtlas/angular.json (3786 bytes)
    CREATE appAtlas/package.json (1316 bytes)
    CREATE appAtlas/README.md (1025 bytes)
    CREATE appAtlas/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
    CREATE appAtlas/tslint.json (2837 bytes)
    CREATE appAtlas/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
    CREATE appAtlas/.gitignore (503 bytes)
    CREATE appAtlas/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
    ....
    CREATE appAtlas/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
    npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, fl                                   atted is its successor.
```

Angular cli version

```
$ ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.0.5
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.5
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.5
@schematics/angular          7.0.5
@schematics/update           0.10.5
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

Node, npm version

```
$ node -v
v10.13.0

$ npm --version
6.4.1
```

Comment: You can you command line argument **—routing** with **new** to including routing. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/new.md . Also why are you assuming it’s supposed to ask about routing specifically?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I believe that's part of the new changes in v7 https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/10/19/angular-cli-7.0/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried another terminal?

I noticed I get the interactive prompts when I use Windows Command Prompt (CMD), but I don't get them in Cygwin. Even if I use `ng new new_project --interactive=true`, Cygwin just skips the prompts and goes with the default options similar to your screenshot.

Comment: Exactly! Same for Angular 8 & 9. Works with Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: Thank you for this, the first time I did this it worked fine, but I was using powershell, and then I had git bash open and it wasn't working and I didn't realize I had switched shells.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I found a solution for the missing questions when you wanna create a new angular project via the command line.

So, try the following steps:

1. Look in the following file, what kind of angular-cli version is installed => `C:\Users\[yourNickname]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json`
2. Delete the directory `@angular`
3. Go to the command line and type `npm cache verify`
4. Then type `npm install -g @angular/cli`
5. Change to your folder where you wanna create the angular project and type `ng new MyApp`

Well, the questions have to display you again :)

Comment: You can do `ng version` to see what version of the cli you have installed...Also, you can do `npm r -g @angular/cli` to remove it globally...

Comment: Yeah my problem was, I had 2 different angular cli versions. The first newest one 7.2.3 was in the path `C:\Users\UserName\...` and the old one with the version 1.0.0.beta was in the path `C:\Users\UserName.DOMAIN\...`.. When I created an angular project it always took the old version from the old account. I don't know why. I did the steps in my answer and it works now.